# Javascript not applying to new class items after changeClass()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to make a script where elements are movable within a container and can be added to the container and moved with a click and then removed with a double click. I got the change class to work from .item to .drag but once it assumes the new class, it doesn't drag.  I'm using the jQuery plugin from here: http://threedubmedia.com/. Any help with getting it to move and where and how to place in the double click feature would be great! Thank you in advance!!

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js" ></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.event.drag.live-2.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
   var $div = $('#container');
   $('.drag')
      .drag("start",function( ev, dd ){
         dd.limit = $div.offset();
         dd.limit.bottom = dd.limit.top + $div.outerHeight() - $( this ).outerHeight();
         dd.limit.right = dd.limit.left + $div.outerWidth() - $( this ).outerWidth();
      })
      .drag(function( ev, dd ){
         $( this ).css({
            top: Math.min( dd.limit.bottom, Math.max( dd.limit.top, dd.offsetY ) ),
            left: Math.min( dd.limit.right, Math.max( dd.limit.left, dd.offsetX ) )
         });   
      });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item').click(function(){ 
       $(this).removeClass('item');
       $(this).addClass('drag'); 
    });         
});
</script>




<div id="container"></div>
<div class="drag" style="left:40px;"></div>
<div class="drag" style="left:120px;"></div>
<div class="drag" style="left:200px;"></div>
<div class="item" style="left:280px;"></div>





<style type="text/css">
.drag {
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid #89B;
   background: #BCE;
   height: 58px;
   width: 58px;
   cursor: move;
   top: 120px;
   }
#container {
   height: 299px;
   border: 1px dashed #888;
   }

.item {
   height: 58px;
   width: 58px;
   background: #000;
}

</style>​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that the drag event handlers are being applied at a time where the div with class .item is NOT a .drag. Later, when it changes...the event handler doesn't get automatically applied.

Your best bet is to use a different selector for applying the drag events. Maybe instead of '.drag' use '#container div'

You can also see if the dragable plugin you are using supports jQuery on()  http://api.jquery.com/on/